# How to not get a div cover my page ?

Tags: css, html, position, web

I'm actually working on a website that should have a div in position fixed on the top of my page. 
But it doesn't work fine : my div on the top is covering a part of my page. I don't understand how to get a solution for this.

The div fixed on the top is ".menutop" :

```
.menutop {
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    color: #428CB7;
}
```

Should I add something in my body configuration ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you show us some example page. Live / on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an element has `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`, it is removed from the flow, so any other elements will act as if it's not there. In order to prevent this causing problems, in your case, add a `margin-top` to your content so that the menu no longer covers it.

Comment: I tried with margin-top and it works fine, but another problem came with this : I have anchors so these anchors are hidden (partially) because of this position:fixed. But on the top of my page it works fine, that's just the middle of the page that cause any problem...

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to add a margin-top to the body for whatever height the menutop is.